# Access data from sqlite database

Tags: android

i have data stored in sqlite database, now it has to be fetched and display it on UI. To do this i have a  cursoradapter.

is this the efficient way to display data?, do we need to use content providers & loaders for this purpose?  what are there advantages & disadvantages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually dont use cursorAdapter instead i create a class "datasource" that handles all databases interactions: create update delete and read where read returns either a single or list of objects containing the data from the database. From there i use a custom adapter to show the data on a list or a gridview.

This tutorial shows how to make that database interaction class http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

and this one show how to create a custom adapter for a listview
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: It's just the name of a class i created with methods that access data on the database like:

public void create(...)

public void update(...)

public MyCustomObject read(int id)

public List<MyCustomObject> readAll()

etc

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, if we use these loaders, my operation would be faster?

Comment: It depends on how much data you are loading. The good thing about the use of cursorloader is that cursorloader will listen for changes in the cursor and refresh the list if any. With a custom adapter you need to tell the adapter when to refresh the list

Comment: No problem, if this answer wass helpfull then please accept it using the checkmark on the left of my answer

Comment: Hi, sure, Any sample example you have to create content provider and access data via sqlite loader

Comment: The vogela tutorial in the link above covers creation and use of a content provider(section 9.4)